# OADate separated from time

Tags: c++, datetime, data-conversion

An old C++ Application has split Date and Time apart.  The application shows a record as having a Date/Time like so:

```
10/21/2015       15:17:22
```

But the data is stored like so:

```
13078(+29220)    3857
```

I know our OADate has an offset of `29220`.  So `13078 + 29220 = 42298`, which is an OADate of `10/21/2015`.  But I don't know how 3857 is supposed to equal `15:17:22`

The actual fields are:

```
int _dateValue;
struct time _timeValue;
```

Another example:

```
10/02/2015       08:40:50
13059 (+29220)   2088
```

I believe the time is originally taken from the c `struct time` function `gettime`  That struct has functions to pull the hour, minute, and seconds.  But I only have the base value, and I'm working with C# and SQL to convert that base value into a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3857 is 0xF11.  By coincidence 0xF == 15 and 0x11 == 17.

2088 is 0x828.  By coincidence 0x8 == 8 and 0x28 == 40.

It looks like the time has the high byte representing the hours, the low byte the minutes, and the seconds are tossed in the bit bucket.

Comment: Howard, this question could have been a riddle and you'd get an award.  Turns out a middle layer application was translating the raw bytes into numbers, thus obscuring the answer which you found in spite of that complication.  The `struct time` of `dos.h` does indeed store the four bytes, but is a messy mix of that information: Minutes, Hours, Hundredths, and Seconds.